# CSS - Heading background color with padding

Tags: css

I have a jsfiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/z9ptvz87/

I'd need the headings to have a background color and same padding on all sides.

I sort of have ot working here but it's with line-height to get it working. Without line-height it looks like this.

https://jsfiddle.net/z9ptvz87/10/

Is there a better way to do this and have padding on the left and right of the text.

```
    *{
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    .block{
        margin: 50px;
        width: 400px;
    }

    .block span{
        display: block;    
    }

    h1, h2{
        background: red;
        display: inline;
        padding:10px;
        line-height: 2em;
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this exact thing before. I couldn't get it to work perfect across Chrome/IE/FF. There is always a 1px gap

Comment: I'm not sure at all what do you mean? If you want to remove the gap between the paragraphs you can set  `h1{
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}`

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `<h1>` elements can't be children of `<span>` elements.

Comment: Can you add an image exactly as you want to look?

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider `h1, h2 { display: inline-block }`? Seems to solve both your issues, if I've understood them correctly.

See https://jsfiddle.net/h7kd9yq8/

Answer (score 0):

if everything's fixed, you can always wrap the content for the different lines inside span tags and style them

```
<h2>
    <span>Sub heading Sub heading Sub</span>
    <span>heading Sub heading Sub</span>
    <span>heading Sub heading</span>
</h2>
```

and then in the css

```
h1 span, h2 span {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    padding: 10px;
    background: red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z9ptvz87/14/

not sure if that's what you wanted to achieve.